# How to sort a list ob objects based on a function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
data class MyUser(
    val id: Int,
    val nameCode: String,
)

val myList : List<MyUser>()

fun getTitleFromCode(nameCode:String) {... return title}
```

How to sort myList alphabetically based on the Titles returned by getTitleFromCode for each MyUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a list using the natural sort order of some key function with [`sortedBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by.html). In your case, your key function will need to get the `nameCode` field and then use that to call `getTitleFromCode`. So this should suffice:

```
myList.sortedBy { getTitleFromCode(it.length) }
```

Note that this will return a new list. If your initial list is mutable and you want to modify it in-place, you can use [`sortBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sort-by.html) instead.